# how File uploaded with media and document portlet should be viewable to respective Organization in liferay6?

Tags: permissions, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

If I have to use document and media portlet in liferay with following facility then how can I achieve that?

[image]

Now From Above picture I want that if organization A user have upload something then it should be viewable by only organization A Users.
right now anyone who have permission to view the document and media portlet cans see my uploaded files.

Answer (score 4):

This level of control is, I think, usually handled by creating sites for your organizations. (There are probably other approaches, which I'd like to see discussed too).

For example, if you create a site for each organization, then there will automatically be a Document and Media library that is private to that site.  The site doesn't need to have any pages or anything if you don't need that.

You create the site for the organization by going to "Users and Orgainizations", clicking through to the org of interest, and then working with the "Organization Site" in the control menu.

[image]

Once the site is created, then everything at the "site" level of the control panel can be selected for the new site.  When so selected, the Documents and Media portlet will show you the top level folder for your organization.

[image]

Now you can use the normal permissions settings for sub-folders or even individual items to restrict availability to "site members", which will be, in this case, "organization members".

Comment: Thanks for your answer.it's really good and explain straight to the point but i know this option already.i can implement the way u said but problem is that i have more then 30 organization and that is not good idea if i have create 30 site and maintain that afterwords.so i m just searching that with the role management i can achieve that??is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well if kirkz answer doesn't solve your issue then I suggest you try the following:

1) For each organisation set up a Liferay "User Role". You'll find "Roles" in the "Portal" section of the Control Panel

2) Assign the relevant users to each of the Roles that you've created based on their Organisation

3) Then go into the Document Library and set the permissions as you need for each of the folders using the Roles you've created. So for example you could have a top level folder for each organisation. Then just set the permissions on the each of those folders so only one Role can access it.

This should solve your issue, however kirkz solution is actually the way you should achieve this hierarchy.

Comment: Hmm..thanks i have thought of like that..just give u feedback as i done with that